# Reversed Distinct?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, distinct

I have a table in my postgres database, with a list of buildings called Buildings_national. In this table, I have a larger number of duplicates, and i need to point them out to have the duplicates deleted.

The thing is, that I need to leave out a single line for every duplicate group, to make sure that one example of the duplicated building is retained in the table.

All buildings has a unique identifier, and every line has a unique identifier as well.

Can anyone recommend a good way to do this? I guess what I am looking for, is a reversed distinct somehow?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: sounds a simple task, but you need to share a structure and some data sample